# Windows 8 will not install on my PC via USB, but will from my Laptop. Error code: 0xC00000005

Tags: macos, windows-8, usb, installation, boot-camp

So, I got a Windows 8 Pro iso and I wiped my laptop and desktop. I used a Macbook Pro and used bootcamp assistant to create a Windows 8 USB bootable drive. When I used it on my laptop, it worked fine and installed perfectly; however, when I use the USB drive on my desktop, the installation errors and fails at "Getting files ready for installation". I noticed that it consistently fails at 97%. It gives me `Error code: 0xC0000005`. I tried burning the iso to a DVD, but it fails at the same place every time!

Comment: Are you doing a clean install or an upgrade?

Comment: @moses A clean install.

Comment: upload the **setupact.log**: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744583%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is the log after attempting with a DVD install: http://pastebin.com/ENvQbZfB

Comment: can you also share the setuperr.log? The log looks fine.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The setuperr.log is completely empty. It's such an obscure problem and it is KILLING me.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Windows 8 manually and avoid Windows' internal setup. May be this solves your problem. I assume you don't have a Windows ToGo or PE ready. I also reckon you can't hook up your desktop's internal drive to your laptop via external case. In this case I will explain how to deploy Windows 8 on your Laptop to a virtual hard drive (VHD) on your laptop/external drive to get something to boot your desktop computer with.

1. First you need to create a VHD. Open **Run** and enter **Diskmgmt.msc**.
2. Click on **Action** --> **Create VHD**. Enter a destination for the file, choose fixed and enter a meaningful size (20GB or more).
3. Once the process is finished, you can see the virtual hard disk among the other disk in the list in the lower half of the window. Right-click on the part that says *Not initialized* and choose **Initialize**.
4. Now, the status of the disk will list its memory as unallocated. Right click on "unallocated" and choose **New Simple Volume**.
5. Click yourself through the dialog, format the drive as NTFS and have a drive letter assigned to it. Now you have a mounted and ready to use virtual drive to install Windows 8 to.
6. Download [GImageX](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-tools/gimagex/). It allows you to extract Windows from its archive.
7. Start it up, click on **Apply**. Under *Source* locate the file *source.wim* on your Windows 8 installation disk. As destination locate the drive letter of the VHD.
8. Click **Apply** and GImageX will extract Windows to the VHD. You can also click *Verify* and *Check* to make sure all files are written correctly and that the archive is error free.
9. Once the process is finished. Unmount the VHD by going back to DiskManagement. Right-click on the disk and click **Detach**.

   By now you have an installed Windows 8 on the VHD. You now have the choice what to do. You can use the VHD on your external drive turning it into Windows ToGo and allowing you to boot your desktop computer. Then you could run the Windows 8 installer and try to see if the installation works properly. You could also use ToGo to install Win8 manually to the hard drive by repeating the above steps but using your desktop hard drive as destination. You could also copy the VHD to your desktop and boot it there and be happy.

   I will describe how to run Win8 off your external drive to boot your desktop enabling you to choose among the above options.
10. Copy the VHD to your external drive.
11. Download [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).
12. Your external drive already seems to be bootable. If it isn't then do the following: In EasyBCD click on **BCD Deployment**. Choose your external drive as destination and click on **Install BCD**. Choose the Vista/7 Bootloader and click on **Write MBR**
13. If you followed step 12 then EasyBCD will ask you if it should load the newly created BCD. Accept. If you skipped it then click on **File** --> **Select BCD** Store and locate the BCD on your external drive.
14. Once the BCD has been loaded click on **Add New Entry** --> in *Disk Image* choose type: Microsoft VHD, enter a name for it, and enter the path to it on your external drive or use the browse button. Click **Add Entry**.
15. Boot your external drive and run through the rest of the Windows 8 installation.

Once you have Windows 8 running on your external drive you can do the same steps above and install Windows 8 manually to the hard drive or just try to run Win8 setup again.

Comment: I am trying this. I will respond in a bit.

Comment: Okay, so this is working so far; however, it is requiring a username and a password. I couldn't find anything useful Googling. How would I get passed this?

Comment: You mean Windows 8 requires you to enter a username and password? Choose local account and generate a user account as usual. For Windows 8.1 this doesn't work and you'll have to create an account on Microsoft's website first with which you then can log in.

Comment: I don't have the option to choose a local account. It just prompts me to enter a username and password.

Comment: Well, then create a Microsoft account and enter its credentials (email/password) during installation.

Comment: No, this is right after creating the VHD and booting from it.

Comment: Yes, I know. That is the rest of the Windows installation that you have to run through so that Windows can actually create your user account. What exactly don't you understand about registering an account online and enter it into the Windows setup?? I don't know how much clearer I could say it?? Last try... Visit this site: http://login.live.com/, REGISTER!!! Enter your credentials into Windows 8. If you don't get that then I suggest finding a video on Youtube that walks you through the installation process as I'm out of words and visual aid would probably best at that point.

Comment: I understand, but there is no installation process. It boots straight to a login screen.

Comment: The hint about using a live login would still apply I think. Just to make sure, can you provide a screenshot? Just so I know we're on the same page here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/If6hHqh This is what happens when I boot. This lasts about 10 minutes.

http://imgur.com/T9T2u4M After the previous screen is over I press 'Enter' and it takes me to this to enter a user and password. I tried my live id, but that wouldn't work. Then it tells me that "The specified domain either does not exist or couldn't be contacted".