# Windows 7 install from DVD onto new hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, dvd

Hard drive failed. Bought new one.
installed hard drive.
downloaded proper iso file onto dvd.
put disk in computer nothing happened.

made boot disc from another win 7 laptop.
put in disk, started computer, got prompts, but nothing that says install win 7. Just wants me to repair or test out drives and such.

Is there a way to just install fresh?

Pre-thanks!
Gidge

Comment: Have you set the CD/DVD driver as the primary boot device through the BIOS?

Comment: yes. I can get the boot disk to work, but switching over to the new disk when it asked for it doesn't work. It's a good copy, all the file is there.

Comment: Could be a problem with your CD/DVD drive. If you have a decent sized (about 3 - 4 GB) pen drive you could try creating a bootable USB stick.

Comment: So i can't switch, I have to have the bootable info on a USB and the iso I downloaded on a DVD? The drive is working great. It read the DVD just fine.

Comment: No, you'll just need the bootable USB stick. There are applications that let you "burn" .iso files onto USB sticks and make them "Bootable." I use rufus, which can be downloaded from here: http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: What do you mean by "downloaded proper iso file onto dvd"? How did you burn the iso?

Comment: If you can't create a bootable setup, you could try installing Windows 7 manually: http://superuser.com/questions/645463/windows-8-will-not-install-on-my-pc-via-usb-but-will-from-my-laptop-error-code/645574#645574

Comment: I used another windows 7 laptop. I put in a DVD that hold 4+ gigs and downloaded the X17-58997.iso . It does nothing alone. So I then made a boot disk from the windows 7 laptop and started the "dead" one with it. I get system recovery options, but not for a new install from the DVD.

Comment: That's not really answering the question. Right now I'm not sure if you burned the iso as container or if you just burned it as a file to the disc. The latter can't work.

Comment: How do I do it correctly? I chose the "DVD acts like a USB" option so things can be added or removed.

Comment: and in regards to Rufus, when I get one (a USB), do I download to it or the computer and run it from the computer please? or directly to the USB.

Comment: That's incorrect - I'm talking about the option you chose when creating the DVD. As Zerobinary99 has mentioned, that method won't make the Disk bootable.

Comment: You need to download suitable software to write the .iso/image to the DVD. I usually use imgburn.

Comment: I have more disks. If you explain i can follow. If you are talking about when you first put in the blank disk, I don't remember. I used the same method for both and the boot disk works fine. If the disc with iso needs to be done differently, I can do it.

Comment: You need to download the imgburn, just google it and you will get it and make bootable disk using their instruction on official site. If you want to make a bootable USB disk then download the WintoFlash, just gooogle it and using it make a bootable USB device and then just change the booting sequence and install the windows. The main culprit with you atm is you don't have a bootable DVD which should work well.

Comment: @Gidge - You don't need two disks. I don't know where you got that idea from. All of the Win 7 setup files will be on the single disk you burn using the .iso file.

Comment: i am downloading ImgBurn onto other win 7 then will copy X17-58997.iso into it and try again. I will let you know if I succeed or fail. Thank you so very much. :)

Comment: yassarikhan786 - There are a lot of site out there with instructions, but for people who know the jargon and such. It's hard to make out exact details. Many were saying use DVD, but boot from USB. Very confusing or it just me. (I would wager on the latter!)

Comment: @Gidge what is the size of ISO you downloaded, I hope its not the repair disk tool for Windows7.

Comment: @avirk - According to the .iso file the OP mentioned above he has the correct file (X17-58997.iso)

Comment: @yassarikhan786 ah I didn't read that, thanks for mention it.

Comment: over 3.2 gigs. X17-58997.iso if it isn't it, I'll just redownload it from the digital river place.

Comment: @Gidge - You have the correct file. Burn the .iso using the method I've suggested below and see where you get.

Comment: @Gidge Or you can use WinISO to make it bootable see [here](http://www.winiso.com/support/tutorials/make-windows7-bootable.html)

Comment: The method is what really matters. Any suitable image burning software will work pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a bootable Windows 7 DVD:

- Download ImgBurn from here: http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download
- When ImgBurn starts, select the option I have highlighted in the below screenshot.

[image: ImgBurn Option 1]

- When the below dialog appears, select the .iso file (`option highlighted in red`) and then click on the option at the bottom (`option highlighted in green`) to burn the .iso onto the DVD correctly.

[image: ImgBurn Option 1]

Once the image burn is successful, try booting with the Disk drive as the primary device.

Comment: It has installed, but now no wireless. I am on my way now! :)